# Find root of each node in graph using NetworkX

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx, graph-theory

How to get root for each node in graph using NetworkX?

This is the sample of my graph:

[image]

Expected result:

Node 4 has root: 0

Node 2 has root: 0

Node 1 has root: 0

Node 0 has root: 0

Node 3 has root: 8

Node 5 has root: 8

Node 8 has root: 8

I created a while loop to get the root of the node and it worked well unless it is very slow.

Is there any efficient way to do this for a big network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a *single root node per component*, you can start by finding all root nodes in the graph, by checking which of the nodes have a degree of `0`. Once identified, iterate over the [`nx.weakly_connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected.weakly_connected_components.html), and find which root node belongs to it:

```
roots = {n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d==0}
d = {}
for comp in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    comp_root = next(root for root in roots if root in comp)
    d.update(dict.fromkeys(comp, comp_root))
```

---

```
print(d)
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 8: 8, 3: 8, 5: 8}
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you, I think the answer is worked, I'm still working on it since there are a strange problem appear.

Comment: Yes that is the intended behaviour right? 1 and 2 are weakly connected since you can only get to node 2 via node 1, not the other way around @SatrioAdiPrabowo

Comment: Ah yes sorry, my bad. The problem is on my data, the assumption somehow didn't hold. I need to clean it. Thank you!